# Default browser doesn't play embedded music from a website

Tags: browser, music

Today I came upon a situation where I had a website which had an embedded player in it which plays sample music. To my surprise I came to know that the Android 2.3 default browser or Opera web browser didn't support it. But I was able to play the music on my iPhone. Is there a way I can make it work on my Android, or is there any other software available for this?

Comment: Is it Flash? Maybe you need to have Flash installed? Download it from the Market.

Comment: but I have adobe flash 10.1 installed already!

Comment: How about Adobe Air?

Comment: Could you post a link to the resource, assuming it's safe to share?

Comment: Website link please?

Comment: @geff: Can't be Flash if it works on an iPhone.

Comment: Hummmm... its not a HTML5 website is it? I say that since you've stated flash 10.1 is already installed but  stock browser/opera does not work! Have you tried dolphin browser?

Comment: Have you tried with other similar websites which play music? It could be an isolated issue due to the way that specific website was developed.

Answer (score 0):

In browswer's setting check if you have made the "plugin load on demand". If so, try "always load".

Comment: It is in "always on" state